# Using for each on a vector in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I would like to iterate over a vector of struct pointers and do some work on each one. I have been trying to work with the following code after researching this problem using google and this site, but have had no luck getting the code to compile.

The loop I am using is as follows, I have tried two types

```
for (auto & i : Mg_Server::servers)
{
    printf("%s\n", i->server_ctx->ns_server->server_data);
}

/*
for (vector<Mg_Server::mg_instance *>::size_type i = 0; i != Mg_Server::servers.size; ++i)
{
    printf("%s\n", Mg_Server::servers[i]->server_ctx->ns_server->server_data);
}*/
```

My vector is declared as static in the header file as

```
class Mg_Server {

public:
    Mg_Server(){}
    ~Mg_Server(){}

   // functions

private:

    struct mg_instance{
        struct mg_server * server_ctx;
        bool running;
    };

    // stuff

    static vector<mg_instance *> servers;

};
```

and I have instantiated the vector in the cpp file using

```
vector<Mg_Server::mg_instance *> Mg_Server::servers;
```

I am compiling this code on CentOS 5.8 using

```
g++44 -Wall -c -std=c++0x "some include directories" -g -D LINUX -m64 -ansi src/mg_server.cpp
```

and I am getting the following errors. Line 58 is where an if statement starts after the for loop.

```
src/mg_server.cpp:47: warning: ‘auto’ will change meaning in C++0x; please remove it
src/mg_server.cpp:47: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
src/mg_server.cpp:58: error: expected primary-expression before ‘if’
src/mg_server.cpp:58: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘if’
src/mg_server.cpp:58: error: expected primary-expression before ‘if’
src/mg_server.cpp:58: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘if’
```

How should I be iterating over a vector in C++0x?

Comment: I think your problem is g++-4.4, not the code itself

Comment: Use `Mg_Server::servers` instead of `Mg_Server:servers`.

Comment: There isn't even an `if` in your code... Please produce a minimal example and supply the entire code. (You are using the correct syntax for a ranged base for loop, perhaps g++4.4 is not new enough?)

Comment: @RSahu Perfect catch! This is when you vote to close as a type :-)

Comment: @RSahu, despite the typo the errors are the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`g++4.4` does not support range-based for-loops. See the [gcc C++11 status](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) page. Support was added in version 4.6. You should [upgrade your compiler](https://superuser.com/questions/381160/how-to-install-gcc-4-7-x-4-8-x-on-centos).

If you are not able to do so, you should use [Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/foreach.html), or just continue using iterators.

Answer (score 1):

```
g++44 -Wall -c -std=c++0x "some include directories" -g -D LINUX -m64 -ansi src/mg_server.cpp
```

`-ansi` overrides `-std=...`. Remove it.